# Project Management Tool Backed by Dropbox

Tags: project-management

Are there any "good" Project Management tools that are capable of synchronizing/backing up data to Dropbox instead of using their own "cloud" solution. A solution in which all data (tasks, schedules and files) are stored using your personal Dropbox account, not the tools backing store.

I'm already using Dropbox, as many other people are, to save their files and don't need another site to again store data on my behalf. Surely, there must be some tool out there that does the job.

Comment: There are a lot of tools using Dropbox. Maybe you could also include your requirements to the features needed?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask for features nor said anything about team size, so I'm going with minimalist and one-person-army.

I am experimenting with Octobox, an open source alternative to Evernote. Notetaking apps can be used for personal project management with little effort, and this one looks promising.

Link: http://useoctobox.com/

Comment: Octobox has shut down.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, many winters ago.